# Average Expected Mean Squared Error = Expected Mean Squared Error?

Tags: self-study, expected-value, mse

In my university lecture, I was introduced to the mean squared error
$ L2 = \frac{1}{N}  \sum_{n=1}^N (t_n - y_n)^2 $ and
its expected value
$ E[L2] = \frac{1}{N} E[\sum_{n=1}^N (t_n - y_n)^2]$, where $ t_n, 1 \leq n \leq N $, come from i.i.d. distributions with gaussian noise (sample values) and $ y_n, 1 \leq n \leq N $, are the values predicted by the linear model that was fit(ted?) to the data set. Now I was wondering whether you could further simplify to $ E[L2] = E[(t_1 - y_1)^2] $, since the $ t_n $ come from identical distributions.

Is my speculation correct?

Comment: Also, sorry for this (probably) low-level question. I know that it is frowned upon on this website, but since my google searches for an answer didn't yield any useful results and the professor and his staff need too long to answer (I have the exam for this lecture next week), I decided to post the question here.

Comment: Since this is connected with course work, I would suggest you add the `self-study` tag. Low-level questions are quite acceptable on XV, provided they do express a genuine questioning from the OP, rather than fishing for homework solutions.

Comment: How did you define $y_n$, is it actually a random variable with a known distribution?